# Calculate Percentile Ranks by Group using Numpy

Tags: numpy, arcpy, percentile

I'm very new with Python, and I want to calculate percentile ranks by group.  My group is wildlife management unit (WMU - string), and ranks are based the value of predicted moose density (PMDEN3 - FLOAT).  The rank value goes into the field RankMD.

My approach was to use the for loop to calculate the 3 ranks within each WMU, but the result is that 3 ranks are created for the entire dbf file (about 23,000 records), without respect to WMU.  Any help is much appreciated.

```
import arcpy
import numpy as np

input = r'K:\Moose\KrigStratPython\TestRank3.dbf' 
arr = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(input, ('PMDEN3', 'Wmu'))
c_arr = [float(x[0]) for x in np.ndarray.flatten(arr)]

for Wmu in arr:
##to create 3 rank for example
    p1 = np.percentile(c_arr, 33)  # rank = 0
    p2 = np.percentile(c_arr, 67)  # rank = 1
    p3 = np.percentile(c_arr, 100)  # rank = 2

#use cursor to update the new rank field
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(input , ['PMDEN3','RankMD']) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row[0] < p1:
                row[1] = 0  #rank 0
            elif p1 <= row[0] and row[0] < p2:
                 row[1] = 1
            else:
                 row[1] = 2

            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is correct, however, your UpdateCursor is iterating over all rows in the table. To get your desired result you need to select out a subset of the table, and then use the update cursor on that. You can do this by passing a query to the where_clause parameter of the [UpdateCursor function](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm).

So you would have a query like this:

```
current_wmu = WMU['wmu']  # This should be the value of the wmu that the for loop is currently on I think it would be WMU['wmu'] but i'm not positive
where_clause = "WMU = '{}'".format(current_wmu)  # format the above variable into a query string
```

and then your UpdateCursor would now be:

`with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(input , ['PMDEN3','RankMD'], where_clause) as cursor:`

Comment: Your solution is very helpful, and the where_clause is working correctly. But for the numpy.percentile method I need to pass it a 1-d array of just PMDEN3 values.  How would I get this array from the UpdateCursor?

Comment: @Rob I'm not sure I follow you. Aren't you passing `c_arr` into the numpy.percentile method? Doesn't that array containt just the PMDEN3 values? The UpdateCursor has access to that variable but i'm not sure what you need it for?

Comment: I first read in an array that contains both yes I used c_arr to pass the PMDEN3 values.

Comment: On what line are you having an issue?

Comment: in my revised code I first read in an array that contains both PMDEN3 and Wmu values (arr1), and I then  manually create an array with Wmu value (e.g., WMUs = ["10", "12A",...].  I loop through this using  for current_wmu in WMUs:, selecting records using the where_clause.  At this point I flatten the array (c_arr) to keep only PMDEN3 values, and pass this array to np.percentile.  Everything is working properly, but would be better to not manually create my WMUs array.  This is my first post on this site.  Don't know if I should be posting my revised code as a new answer?

Comment: You can add an edit to your question. Why are you creating the WMUs array? You can't just access the WMUs from the `arr` variable like i did in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Based on suggestion from BigGerman, I revised my code and this is now working.  Script loops through each WMU value, and calculates rank percentile within each group based on PMDEN.  To improve the script I should create an array of WMU values from my input file rather than manually creating the array.

```
import arcpy
import numpy as np

#fields to be calculated
fldPMDEN = "PMDEN"
fldRankWMU = "RankWMU"

input = r'K:\Moose\KrigStratPython\TestRank3.dbf' 
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(input, "stratLayerShpNoNullsLyr")
WMUs = ["10", "11A", "11B", "11Q", "12A"]
for current_wmu in WMUs:
    ##to create 3 rank for example
        where_clause = "Wmu = '{}'".format(current_wmu)  # format the above variable into a query
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("stratLayerShpNoNullsLyr", [fldPMDEN,fldRankWMU], where_clause) as cursor:
            arr1 = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray("stratLayerShpNoNullsLyr", [fldPMDEN,fldRankWMU], where_clause)
            c_arrS = [float(x[0]) for x in np.ndarray.flatten(arr1)]
            p1 = np.percentile(c_arrS, 33)  # rank = 3
            p2 = np.percentile(c_arrS, 67)  # rank = 2
            p3 = np.percentile(c_arrS, 100)  # rank = 1 (highest density)
            for row in cursor:
                if row[0] < p1:
                    row[1] = 3  #rank 0
                elif p1 <= row[0] and row[0] < p2:
                     row[1] = 2
                else:
                     row[1] = 1
                cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Rob, each record in the table has a WMU value correct? If you extract all of the WMU values as a list you can then convert this to a "set". In Python a "set" is an unordered collection that cannot contain duplicate items, so this will eliminate any duplicates; giving you an interable of the distinct values for WMU. For example, If you have the `WMU_list = ["10", "10", "11A", "11A", "11B", "11B", "11Q", "12A"]` then `set(WMUs)` will return `set(['10', '12A', '11A', '11Q', '11B'])` you can then use the set in your for loop.

Comment: @BigGerman, your solution should work, but I am still getting all the duplicate records.  I tried `input = r'K:\TestRank3.dbf'`, and 
`arr = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(input, ('Wmu'))`, then 
`WMU_List = set(arr)`   then `print (WMU_List)`.  I get the full list of duplicates

Comment: Since arr is a NumPyArray and not a list, i'm not sure if set works the same way. It looks like NumPy arrays actually have a method to return an array of unique values: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html

Comment: @BigGerman, I tried `np.unique(arr)`, and it returned a unique array (yay!), but the print statement produced [(u'10',) (u'11A',) (u'11B',)...], which has a different format than my WMU_list ["10", "11A", "11B", ...].   This caused errors, I then converted the array to a str format using 'WMU_unique.astype('str')`, and it worked!  Problem is solved.